# R formula with as.factor(): any way to specify the argument as a variable content instead of directly by name?

Tags: r

For the sake of the following discussion, I'll create this fake training data frame:

```
> dataset = data.frame(result=c("yes","yes","no","no","no"),
                       s1=seq(0,8,2), s2=seq(1,9,2))
> dataset
  result s1 s2
1    yes  0  1
2    yes  2  3
3     no  4  5
4     no  6  7
5     no  8  9
>
```

I'm trying to train multiple kernlab KSVM models from multiple data frames similar to the one shown above. The `result` column is actually named different for each of the data frames (it's named according to what the model trained with that dataset is supposed to be predicting).

I'm still pretty new to R, so the syntax I'm using is just modeled (no pun intended) after code I cut-and-pasted from Rattle's log tab:

```
trainedModel = ksvm(as.factor(result) ~ ., data=dataset[,c(input, target), ...)
```

...where `result` is the name of the column in the `dataset` data frame. I understand that `as.factor(result) ~ .` is a formula, and that what this means is that the stuff on the left side of the `~` is somehow derived from the stuff on the right side of the `~`, and that the `.` just means "everything else not specified on the left side of the `~`". At least I think that's what it means.

My problem is that I want to be able to create & train these models programmatically, and the name of the target column in the input dataset will change.

How can I specify "colnames(dataset)[1]" (i.e. the name of the column dynamically determined, without *knowing* the name of the column at coding time), in the code `as.factor(result)`?

Comment: I could be misunderstanding you, but I think `as.formula(paste(...))` is what you're looking for. You can build the formula using `paste()` with variables as they are produced.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen OK, thank you very much, `as.formula(paste0("as.factor(", colnames(dataset)[1], ") ~ ."))` worked quite nicely. Would you like to post an answer, or is this such a silly simple question you think I should just delete it?

Comment: phonetagger: Nah, don't delete it. I agree, @BrandonBertelsen should post that as an answer. I think it's helpful. Just because a question has a simple answer doesn't mean other people won't have the same question. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?as.formula`, allows you to build a formula using `paste`. Putting these together you can create a formula based on variables, for example:

```
as.formula(paste("as.factor(",result_column,") ~ ."))
```